# Mongodb java driver query with binary _id

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a few entries in a mongodb database. They have binary _ids. If I query with a mongo client like robomongo I'm able to find the entry I'm looking for:

```
db.getCollection('comment').find({"_id" : new BinData(0,"nCgNlWhzJM9/lHDVQmXQrg==")})
```

However, I'm having serious issues with doing the same in java. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
final MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("comment");

mongoCollection
             .find(eq("_id", new Binary((byte) 0, "nCgNlWhzJM9/lHDVQmXQrg==".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))))
             .first()
```

Sadly this is not working. Trying to find an item with a string type works (like eq("author", "someone) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your _id value `nCgNlWhzJM9/lHDVQmXQrg==` is shown Base64 encoded, so your java query should be written:

```
    Document doc = mongoCollection
    .find(eq("_id", new Binary((byte) 0, Base64.getDecoder().decode("nCgNlWhzJM9/lHDVQmXQrg=="))))
    .first();
```

To decode the key before using it to create the binary filter.